# Ubuntu in VirtualBox File Modified Time in Future and PHP slow file operations

Tags: ubuntu, php, virtualbox

For some reason, some of my files have a last modified date in the future.  In addition to this, file operations in PHP are SUPER slow.  For example, rebuilding the Symfony2 cache can take over 40 seconds (its takes 1-2 on my MacBook Pro).

[image: Notice the time for ListingsCRUDController.php]

Notice the time for ListingsCRUDController.php.  It just says "2012".  In order see the date more clearly I ran `ls --time-style="full-iso" -l`

[image]

For some reason it shows that this file's last modified date is ~5 hours into the future.

System time:
[image]

To make things more confusing, the system will intermittently speed up.  Suddenly, my app will start serving requests in 1-2 seconds (down from 40 seconds) for no apparent reason.  I mean I don't do anything to my code/system config - it just changes.

Also, during a slow PHP request, the php5-fpm process (nginx) uses 100% of the CPU for the duration of the request.

This is the second VM this has happened on and I need to know why its doing this.  It has become unusable.

**Information About My Setup**

VirtualBox 4.2.0

Host: Macbook Pro

Guest: Ubuntu Server 12.04

Package dkms is installed

Timezones match for Ubuntu and PHP.

**Things I've Tried**

Both Apache and Nginx.

APC enabled and disabled.

Xdebug enabled and disabled.

1 processor up to 4 processors.

1gb memory up to 4gb memory.

I've installed Ubuntu using the regular kernel and the VM kernel.